# Questions about my program and Polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

Ok, so basically I'm creating a program which allows the user to select a shape (triangle, square, circle) and then it takes in a int and calculates the boundary length and area.

I have no problem doing this and have a program that's working perfectly. (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c63a03c129560a7b7434 4 classes) But now I have to implement this with polymorphism concepts and I'm honestly struggling as to how to do it.

I have a basic idea of what I want to do when it comes to inheritance

```
                                       Main
                                         |
                                       Shapes
                                       /  |  \
                                triangle circle square
```

But I don't understand how I'm supposed to override when all the methods within the triangle/square/circle classes are unique, there are no "abstract" methods as such that I could inherit from the "Shapes" class.

If somebody could make look quickly at the code I linked and suggest a way to do this it would be much appreciated.

Sorry if I was bad at explaining this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, they each share a similar constructor `A(double)`. They all share common methods: `getArea(double) & getBoundaryLength(double)`. If you put all of those, as abstract methods and a required constructor, into an abstract class, it should work.

Comment: getArea and getBoundaryLength can definitely be abstracted. Remember that abstraction means "find the common part among 2 different things"

Comment: What is exactly you want? Are you trying to access methods in the derived class which are unique to a particular derived class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be a start:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    protected double length;
    public Shape(double length) {
      this.length = length;
    }
    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getBoundaryLength();
}
```

And one possible implementation

```
public class Circle extends Shape {
  @Override
  public double getArea() {
    return length * length * Math.PI;
  }
  @Override
  public double getBoundaryLength() {
    return 2 * length * Math.PI;
  }
}
```

Within main:

```
Shape shape = new Circle(scan.nextDouble()); // Use variable of type shape here

..

// this code is the same for all shapes
double boundaryLength = shape.getBoundaryLength(length);
double area = shape.getArea(length);
System.out.println("Boundary Length = " + Math.round(boundaryLength));
System.out.println("Area = " + Math.round(area));
```

Comment: I think I will do it this way, I really appreciate the help. I think I got muddled up in my own thinking if that makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you don't have a common interface between your shape objects.

You could maybe do something like this:

```
public interface Shape {
  // whatever polymorphic behavior you want
}
```

and then each of your classes would be declared like this:

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
  // ...
}

public class Triangle implements Shape {
  // ...
}

public class Square implements Shape {
  // ...
}
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much but I think I will go with micha's answer. Thanks for taking the time to help me out though.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is to have the methods that appear in all the child classes as an abstract method in Shape.  If you do this, you are able to work with Shape objects as Shapes without knowing which kind of shape they are.  For example, you do this:

```
Shape c = new Circle(50);
System.out.println(c.getArea());
```

This would result in printing the correct area of the shape, as calculated by a circle, while still using it as a shape (the second line knows nothing about its origins of being created as a circle, but will still calculate as one).  This is only doable through thus usage of inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

As @KepaniHaole mentioned you can create an interface and make your classes implement it.
Another way is to create an `abstract class`, implement inside it methods that are common between the three of your classes, and leave the implementation of the methods that aren't common to their own classes.

For example:

```
public abstract class Shape 
{
    int x, y;
    void moveTo(int newX, int newY)
    {
       //implementation
    }

   abstract void draw();
   abstract void resize();
}
```

So `moveTo` can be shared among the three of the classes, whereas `draw` and `resize` can be implemented individually by each class.

The good things about `abstract classes` is that you can have implemented methods inside them and even fields. This is not possible with interfaces.